# Deploy Docker Image With Github Action

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have a Github Action which consist to tag, build and deploy a docker image.
When there is a pull request I just do the build job with this file: `build.yml`

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Build

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  docker:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY }}

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: docker build
        run: | # Tag the image with the commit hash
          docker build -t $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY .
          docker tag $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY:latest $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY:$(git log -1 --pretty=%h)
```

And for the deployment I have to build and deploy with this file: `deploy.yml`

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Deploy

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  docker:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY }}

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: docker login
        env:
          DOCKERHUB_USER: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USER }}
          DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER -p $DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN

      - name: docker build
        run: | # Tag the image with the commit hash
          docker build -t $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY .
          docker tag $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY:latest $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY:$(git log -1 --pretty=%h)

      - name: docker push
        run: |
          docker push $DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY
```

For me there is a repetition with the build section but I did not found how can I use a dependency in jobs on different files. It is not working.

How can I tell github action that the deploy section depends on the build ?, with 2 different files.

link: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#creating-dependent-jobs

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them into one CI/CD pipeline. This should be triggered by both `push`es and `pull_request`s in master. This has several advantages;

- If the build fails, the pipeline is automatically aborted 
  (to be absolutely sure, you can add `if: ${{ success() }}`!
- No duplicate steps, `docker build` is only defined once.
- Steps can still only be performed on a `push` or `pull_request` by using *conditions*:

```
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }} // OR
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
```

- Fewer pipelines to maintain!